# Prolog With Java Query

Tags: prolog

Hi Somebody can Help me with this problem, i need the follow tables in prolog and i need todo some query to this table like the follow.

2.1 Get the plate, number of doors, model, reference and name of the owner
vehicles having a given displacement.
2.2. Get the plate, reference number and owner name doors of the vehicles that
have affiliate contract type and a given model.
2.3. Get the plate, date of revision, ID of the owner of the vehicles with revisions in a
given state and insurer corresponds to a given.
2.4. Get the model plate, ID of owner and contact number of the vehicles with a
and number of gates given speed below a given amount.
2.5. Get the plate, reference, cedula Owners of older vehicles (his model is
lower).

in this paste are the tables

http://pastebin.com/BBue2nFE

please it's somebody can help me Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your posting is hard to understand.

Is your problem that you have data in a relational database and need to access it from Prolog?  If so, we need to know which Prolog you are using and which database.